# Filter top by group

Tags: sql, oracle11g

We have the following situation to query in Oracle.

We have  orders and transactions, with an order being mapped to multiple transactions.

```
Order
orderId|customer|.....

Transaction
orderId|transactionId|transactionDate|.....
```

We need to display the latest transaction for each order.  How do I go about it in Oracle 11g?

Comment: I am concerned that, as per other questions from you, you appear to have acquired good answers and you have ignored them. I have downvoted **and** voted to close (easily too broad, since you have not demonstrated any prior effort).

Answer (score 0):

This is one method

```
select t1.* from transactions t1 inner join
(
select orderId,max(transactiondate) as transactiondate from transactions
group by orderId
) t2 on o.orderId=t.orderId and t1.transactiondate =t2.transactiondate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a *Windowed Aggregate Function* to find the last row:

```
select ...
from
 (
   select ...,
      row_number() 
      over (partition by orderId
            order by transactionDate desc) as rn
   from ...
 ) dt
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this one OK:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN transactions t1
ON t1.orderId = o.orderId
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM transactions t2
  WHERE t2.orderId      = t1.orderId
  AND t2.transactionDate>t1.transactionDate
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to accomplish this. As has already been shown above, using analytic function like DENSE_RANK AND ROW_NUMBER can be one way. But frankly using analytic function to do something elementary like this seems to be a bit overkill.

Please see the below to do this in a simpler way. Please note, joining the 'Transaction' table after 'Order' table is not strictly necessary if only column needed from 'Order' table is orderId, as the same is available in 'Transaction' table too. I deliberately kept the table in the join, only because if there is a necessity to fetch some more column from 'Order' that can also be done using this query, just by adding those columns in the select list, thus making the query flexible in fetching data from both the tables.

```
SELECT ord.orderId, tran.*
FROM Order ord, Transaction tran
(SELECT orderId, MAX(transactionDate) mtransactionDate
 FROM Transaction 
 GROUP BY orderId) maxtran
WHERE ord.orderId = tran.orderId
AND tran.transactionDate = maxtran.mtransactionDate
AND tran.orderId = maxtran.orderId
```